# Querying GCP Datastore backup without overwriting live database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, leveldb

I am trying to access a backup created by [gcloud datastore export](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/export). I only want to access some entries in the backup and don't want to modify the live database to do so.

So far I have tried:

**Restore using [gcloud datastore import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/import):** it seems like my only option is to limit the namespaces and kinds that are being overwritten from the backup. If I do not want to overwrite anything, I can create a new GCP project and restore to that one. However, this is a tough option because I don't control billing for my organization and the restored backup would exceed the free tier.

**Parse the backup files manually:** The [import export guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#gcloud) mentions:

> The output of a managed export uses the [LevelDB log format](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/log_format.md).

I wrote a parser based on the grammar linked above. The good news is that it resembles my data in a hex editor. Unfortunately, it seems like each record is wrapped in some undocumented binary format that also contains several copies of the namespace, kind, and key. I was not sure how to parse this.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Download the backup from the GCS bucket:

```
mkdir ~/my-datastore-backups
gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-datastore-backups/2020-07-30T09:00:07_35225/ ~/my-datastore-backups
```

[Import the backup to the datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import):

```
curl -X POST localhost:8081/v1/projects/my-project:import \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"input_url":"/home/user/my-datastore-backups/2020-07-30T09:00:07_35225/2020-07-30T09:00:07_35225.overall_export_metadata"}'
```